# Nonlinear partial differential equation of first order

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've got the Farlow's book, and it says that this:

$u=\phi(x-g(u)t)$

is an implicit solution of the nonlinear problem:

$u_t+g(u)u_x=0$

$u(x,0)=\phi(x)$

with $x,t\in\mathbb{R},t>0$.

But, how can I arrive to that conclusion? I mean, if I have the implicit expression, I can show it is a solution, without big problems... but if I don't have that expression, how can I get it?

I really feel that proposition like a spoiler. I can use it to solve problems, but I don't know where does it come from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$u_t + g(u)u_x = 0$$

Using the [method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), we find

$$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1 \implies dt = ds \ \ (1)\\
\frac{dx}{ds} = g(u) \implies \frac{dx}{dt} = g(u) \ \ (2) \\
\frac{du}{ds} = 0 \implies \frac{du}{dt} = 0 \ \ (3)$$

Now, from $(2)$, after integrating we see that

$$x(t) = g(u)t + x_0 \ \ (4)$$

where $x(0) = x_0$ is your constant of integration.

Now, from $(3)$, we see that $u$ is constant in $t$ i.e.

$$u(x, t) = f(x_0) \ \ (5)$$

where we have a *function* of integration and **not** a constant (why?).

So substituting $(4)$ into $(5)$

$$u(x, t) = f(x - g(u)t)$$

Applying the initial condition

$$\begin{align}
u(x, 0) &= f(x) \\
&= \phi(x) \\
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$u(x, t) = \phi(x - g(u)t)$$